# How does Windows 10 DNS work in regards to a Domain Controller?

Tags: networking, windows-10, vpn, dns

I have a local network, 10.10.10.1

The local network uses a VPN to connect to a cloud domain controller running DNS at 172.16.0.1

In order to join and interact with the domain, Windows 10 requires the primary DNS to be 172.16.0.1 and I have the secondary DNS as 10.10.10.1

[DNS Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qR3Jt.png)

We added a failover connection and we aren't able to add a second VPN connection for the failover connection. The DNS is used for Windows logins and not much more. Not having a VPN for the failover connection doesn't cause any problems for the Windows computers.

The problem is with our VOIP phones and printers. Many of the VOIP phones have computers attached to them through Ethernet, making VLAN's somewhat complicated.

When the failover kicks in, the phones and printers sit and spin for a minute while they attempt to connect to the DNS server at 172.16.0.1 and eventually start working again when they use the secondary DNS at 10.10.10.1

From my understanding, the Domain Controller (linux in this case) and/or Windows 10 requires that the primary DNS be the Domain Controller.

Is there a way (a group policy, registry edit, or script) that forces Windows to use the secondary DNS when attempting to contact the domain controller so that I can set my primary DNS as 10.10.10.1 for all the rest of my equipment?

If not that, any other ideas that might work?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way (a group policy, registry edit, or script) that forces Windows to use the secondary DNS when attempting to contact the domain controller

No, the secondary DNS server is only used as a fallback if the primary DNS is unresponsive – Windows won't split their usage based on domain queried. At most, you'd

> From my understanding, the Domain Controller (linux in this case) and/or Windows 10 requires that the primary DNS be the Domain Controller.

No, client system just requires that the Active Directory domain (and all its subdomains) be *resolvable* by whatever DNS server you're using, but doesn't care whether it's direct or whether it goes through 10 DNS servers.

So if you have a LAN domain like `example.corp` and AD is configured to be a subdomain of that, you can add a NS record pointing there – a delegation. (That's the same mechanism which allows you to resolve all the millions of Internet domains without having to directly configure each of their nameservers.)

```
ad.example.corp.      NS     dc1.ad.example.corp.
dc1.ad.example.corp.  A      172.16.0.1
dc1.ad.example.corp.  AAAA   2001:db8:e27f::7
```

If the LAN doesn't have its own domain, or if they're completely separate branches, then regular DNS delegations probably cannot be used – but your LAN DNS server most likely :

```
# dnsmasq
server=/ad.example.corp/172.16.0.1

# Unbound
stub-zone:
    name: "ad.example.corp"
    stub-addr: 172.16.0.1
```

All of those mechanisms, however, require that the LAN DNS server can reach the AD domain controller, so there must be some form of routing or VPN between them.